# Why are my App Engine query counts incorrect in my tests?

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create tests to verify that my entities are being saved in the database.
When I put breakpoints in the post function, I can see that the customer count changes after the record is saved.

```
> /Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/main.py(137)post()  
-> customer.put()  
(Pdb) l  
134             query = Customer.query()  
135             orig_customer_count = query.count()  
136             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
137  ->         customer.put()  
138             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
139             query_params = {'leadbook_name': leadbook_name}  
140             self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))  
141       
142     config = {}  
(Pdb) orig_customer_count  
5  
(Pdb) c  
> /Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/main.py(139)post()  
-> query_params = {'leadbook_name': leadbook_name}  
(Pdb) l  
134             query = Customer.query()  
135             orig_customer_count = query.count()  
136             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
137             customer.put()  
138             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
139  ->         query_params = {'leadbook_name': leadbook_name}  
140             self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))  
141       
142     config = {}  
143     config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {  
144         'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',  
(Pdb) query.count()  
6
```

The entities also show up in the Datastore Viewer.

However, my test keeps failing.

```
F  
======================================================================  
FAIL: test_guest_can_submit_contact_info (dermalfillersecrets.functional_tests.NewVisitorTest)  
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/functional_tests.py", line 75, in test_guest_can_submit_contact_info  
    self.assertNotEqual(orig_custs, query.count())  
AssertionError: 0 == 0
```

This is the functional_test.py file contents:

```
import os, sys  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3")  

import unittest  
from selenium import webdriver  
from google.appengine.api import memcache  
from google.appengine.ext import db  
from google.appengine.ext import testbed  
import dev_appserver    
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2  


class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):  

    def setUp(self):  
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()  
        self.testbed.activate()  
        #self.testbed.setup_env(app_id='dermalfillersecrets')  
        self.testbed.init_user_stub()  
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()  
        self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()  

        # setup the dev_appserver  
        APP_CONFIGS = ['app.yaml']  

        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)  

    def tearDown(self):  
        self.browser.quit()  
        self.testbed.deactivate()  

    def test_guest_can_submit_contact_info(self):  
        from main import Customer  
        query = Customer.query()  
        orig_custs = query.count()  
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8080')  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_name').send_keys("Kallie Wheelock")  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_street').send_keys("123 main st")  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_phone').send_keys('(404)555-1212')  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_zip').send_keys("30306")  
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('submit').submit()  
        # this should return 1 more record  
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
        query = Customer.query()   
        self.assertNotEqual(orig_custs, query.count())  
        assert(Customer.query(Customer.name == "Kallie Wheelock").get())  
        # Delete the Customer record  
        Customer.query(Customer.name =="Kallie Wheelock").delete()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup the testbed to imitate strong consistency (if its not important for your application for them to be actually consistent):

```
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_util

policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=1)
testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=policy)
```

Read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Writing_High_Replication_Datastore_tests).

BTW, consider to use [nosetests](https://github.com/Trii/NoseGAE) plugin, to make your tests cleaner.

Comment: I added all 3 of those lines to my NewVisitorTest.setUp() and I'm still getting the exact same errors.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

p.s. I have been initiating tests with: nosetests --with-gae

Comment: # this sets testbed to imitate strong consistency
        from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_util

Comment: policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=1)

Comment: self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=policy)

Comment: # the 3 lines above are what I added to NewVisitor.Setup()

Answer (score 1):

Appengine high replication datastore works on a 'eventually consistent'  model. 
i.e. if you insert an entity  it is not guaranteed that subsequent queries will fetch that entity. There will be a non zero amount of time delay.
In order to make your queries consistent you have to make sure your entities belong to the same entity group and make use of ancestor queries.

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/